# Запретить оптимизацию копирования участка памяти

Tags: c++, gcc

Каким образом запретить компилятору (GCC) оптимизировать цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    dst[i] = src[i];
```

который превращается в вызов:

```
memcpy(dst, src, 256);
```

**UPD**

Интересует именно точечное решение, без отключения других оптимизаций, предотвращающее скрытые вызовы других функций.

Comment: А ключик типа `-Od` или какой там в GCC, не пробовали?

Comment: @Harry как рабочее решение, да, с выносом в отдельную функцию и отключением оптимизации для неё. Больше интересует возможность запретить компилятору выходить за пределы адресного пространства одной функции.

Comment: Хм. А для чего могло такое понадобиться?

Comment: @VladD ф-ия memcpy лежит в области памяти, которая в момент работы цикла недоступна.

Comment: Тогда наоборот, нужна предельная оптимизация, при которой `memcpy` заинлайнится :)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: А, вы под экзотической платформой? Может быть, в этом случае имеет смысл воспользоваться платформозависимыми решениями. Может быть, для вашей платформы можно что-то такое указать?

Comment: @VladD можно для отдельной ф-ии отключить оптимизацию, тогда проблема снимается. Но интересно запретить компилятору делать предположения о наличии тех или иных функций, кроме явно вызываемых.

Comment: @Harry с предельной оптимизацией ещё хуже - memcpy реализуется через DMA controller )

Comment: Вроде такой есть ключик, надо попробовать -fno-builtin-memcpy

Comment: Напишите цикл на ассемблере.

Comment: У Вас получается в вопросе одно, а судя по комментариям - хотелось бы большего.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо за замечание, поправил вопрос.

Comment: Так а что такое вообще "отключение оптимизаций"? Как вы себе это представляете? Какой код в данном случае должен получиться "без оптимизаций"? Какие инструкции процессора компилятору можно использовать, а какие нельзя?

Comment: @AnT интересует запрет скрытых (не указанных явно) вызовов каких-либо функций. В данном случае компилятор заменяет цикл вызовом memcpy.

Comment: [оно?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5580140/3240681)

Answer (score 1):

gcc -O0 -S test.c

ключ -O[0|1|2|3|s|fast|g] задает как оптимизировать код
-O0 - не оптимизировать
про остальные точно описано [по ссылке](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) 
что оптимизируется при выбранном ключе

P.S. обычно при олимпиадном программировании используется -O2